# Disabling Input Field when value is pre-populated

Tags: angularjs

An edit, and add user form group utilizes the same view. However on edit, the username, password, and other details are autofilled into the form instead of presenting a blank form. The form (specifically for username) needs to be disabled, if and only if the field was pre-populated.

Using ng-readonly or ng-disabled works when the user is editing the form (username is disabled if username.length is true).

```
ng-readonly="username.length"
```

However, when the user is creating a new profile, typing in one letter into the username field will disable it, as ng-readonly recognizes that the username field has a length of 1. How would I set it so that Angular only checks to make the field read-only once instead of constantly monitoring changes in the field. The other problem is that I don't want Angular to completely ignore the field's changes, as validation (such as min length and isrequired) still need to fire.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a way of knowing whether or not the form is in 'add' or 'edit' mode.  Can you just replace the condition of ng-readonly with an "isAdding" boolean?